# Unable to import ParrotOS OVA file in VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation, parrot-os

I have downloaded new version of **Parrot OS .OVA** file from their official website. When I try to import it to my **VMware Workstation**, It's showing following error:

[image: Error]

> The import failed because Parrot-security-4.6_virtual.ova did not pass OVF specification conformance or virtual hardware compliance check.

The Parror OS version is **4.6** and format **.OVA**

My VMware Workstation version **14.1.2**

[image: My VMware all info]

Comment: For a workaround, try to extract the VMDK file from that OVA file with 7zip. Do it in command line, GUI is slow.

Answer (score 1):

Click on retry two or three times - it will install, Had the same issue. Worked for me.